# Most likely value of negative binomial random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X$ is a negative binomial random variable let's say with $p =0.2$ and $r = 4$ then how can we calculate most likely value of $X$? 
I thought it is expected value but that is $20$ and I guess most likely value is mode of data so this can't be answer. How will we calculate most likely value in this?

Answer (score 2):

For the parametrization $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{x+r-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^x, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\},$$ it is easy to observe $$\frac{\Pr[X = x+1]}{\Pr[X = x]} = \frac{(1-p)(x+r)}{x+1}.$$  If this ratio exceeds $1$, then the probability is still increasing as a function of $x$; i.e., $$\Pr[X = x+1] > \Pr[X = x] \iff (1 - p)(x+r) > x+1,$$ or equivalently, $$x < \frac{r(1-p) - 1}{p}.$$  So you will want to search around this value to get the mode.